# send data to express.js in a for loop

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I need help with this, I really can't crack this one up.
I have this web site using `Node.js` to call `mySQL` queries and display them as tables, each in it's own page. To do so, I created 4 objects that include a name, a title and the query. when I have this code going four times (from `queryPage[0]` to `queryPage[3]`), It works great. But i want to put it into a for loop so I won't need 4 repetitions of the same lines, but then it doesn't work. the pages don't load... Any idea what is going on?

```
connection.query(queryPage[0].query, function(err, rows) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var i in rows) {
    arr[i] = rows[i];
  }
  app.get('/' + queryPage[0].name, function(req, res) {
    res.render('pages/' + queryPage[0].name, {
      title: queryPage[0].title,
      data: arr
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hows your code work? Is it in working condition?

Comment: If i understand correctly, when you start your app you get data for each page from db and setup a route for it then when a request comes in for one of the routes you serve the rows. This means if you change data in db you still get old data on all pages. Is that correct? I mean most people would query db when the request comes in so you get latest data.

Comment: That's interesting an I didn't think of that. thank you. Yet, that is not my issue. I'm just trying to understand why this code works when I write it 4 times but not in a for loop

Comment: Since I can't see your for loop it's hard to tell what the problem is but most probably one of the route should work. The reason is in a for loop if you use queryPage[i] then you are creating 4 times route with name of last page queryPage[3].name this is due to asynchronous nature of node.js

Comment: You know, That's exactly what happened! The last one always worked. Is there another way to loop through the routes?

Comment: I think it's a bad practice to define routes the way you do it. The code in my answer bellow will work the way you want it. As a benefit you always get fresh data from db. If you need any help with implementing that, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something more like this

```
var queryPage = [ ... ];
// This route catches all request
app.get('/:name', function (req, res, next) { 
    // :name = req.params.name

    var page;
    for(var i = 0, l = queryPage.length; i < l; i++)
        if(queryPage[i].name === req.params.name) {
            page = queryPage[i];
            break;
        }

    // Check the page exists
    if(!page) return res.status(404).send('Not found');
    // if(!page) return next();

    connection.query(page.query, function(err, rows) {
        res.render('pages/' + page.name , {
            title: page.title, 
            data: rows
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Maybe (make it, definitely) I'm lacking knowledge, but i don't understand what the `'/:name'` is used for. I think your way will work but I don't know how to configure it to my code...

Comment: If the address is example.com/something then :name is *something* so req.params.name will be *something*